# Publish Front-End (Website) on Kestrel web server in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: backend, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel

We build a .net core backend using minimal API. (ASP.Net Core 6.0)
As far I understand ASP.NET uses Kestrel server.
Is it possible that Kestrel will serve also front-end website?
Or we have to add nginx/apache/any other server?

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but **yes**! Kestrel will serve your frontend without any issues.

I'm personally serving up a built Angular app, or, in development, I use the Angular CLI to serve the frontend, and Kestrel only acts as the API.

I'm only running ASP.NET Core 3.1 myself, the setup did require a little digging, but it must have only improved by now!